# $\int_{\partial\Omega_t}(h-H)|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}|^2=0 \Rightarrow$ $\Omega_t$ is ball

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Consider the firt eigenvalue $\lambda$ of Laplacian on bounded mutative domain $\Omega_t\subset \mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary $\partial \Omega_t$. By my calculation, $u$ is the eigenfunction of $\lambda$, I have 
$$
\frac{d\lambda}{dt} =\int_{\partial\Omega_t} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t }\nabla u\cdot \nu
$$
If we deform the boundary $\partial\Omega_t$ by volume preserving mean curvature flow 
$$
\partial_tx=(h(t)-H(x,t))\nu   ~~~x\in\partial \Omega_t 
$$
$\nu$ is the outer normal vector. $H(x,t)$ is the mean curvature , and $h(t)$ is the mean of $H(x,t)$ i.e.
$$
h(t)=\frac{\int_{\partial\Omega_t} H  dS}{\int_{\partial\Omega_t} dS}
$$
then, I have 
$$
\frac{d\lambda}{dt}=\int_{\partial\Omega_t}(h-H)|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}|^2
$$
I feel it is hard to know $\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$ is negative or positive, I have asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265511/principal-eigenvalue-of-laplacian-under-volume-preserving-mean-curvature-flow). So, step back, I want to show it is ball when 
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega_t}(h-H)|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}|^2=0
$$
But I still don't know how to do it.